# How can I say "provide" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice

I want to say:

> I will provide the necessary books.

I translated it like this:

> Ich werde die notwendigen Bücher bereitstellen.

However, I am not sure whether *bereitstellen* is the correct word or not.

Comment: I think this question should stay open, because it reduces the translation request to a single source of concern which is (in my opinion) well-addressed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Learn: You *never* translate words. You *always* translate meanings!

This is not only true in case of »to provide«, this is **ALWAYS** true!

---

The english verb »to provide« has, according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/provide), six different meanings (plus two additional meanings which seem to be obsolete), and for each meaning you can have different words in German:

1. To make a living; earn money for necessities.

   > **to provide for somebody = für jemanden sorgen**
   >
   > It is difficult to **provide** for my family working on minimum wage.
   >   Es ist schwierig, für meine Familie zu **sorgen** wenn man für einen Mindestlohn arbeitet.
2. To act to prepare for something.

   > **to provide something = etwas bereitstellen, etwas zur Verfügung stellen**
   >
   > I will **provide** the necessary books.
   >   Ich werde die notwendigen Bücher **bereitstellen**.
   >   Ich werde die notwendigen Bücher **zur Verfügung stellen**.
3. To establish as a previous condition; to stipulate.

   > **to provide something = etwas voraussetzen** (*voraussetzen* is a [separable verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb))
   >
   > The contract **provides** that the work be well done.
   >   Der Vertrag **setzt voraus**, dass die Arbeit gut gemacht wird.
   >
   > I'll lend you the money, **provided** that you pay it back by Monday.
   >   Ich werde dir das Geld leihen, **vorausgesetzt** du zahlst es bis Montag zurück.
4. To give what is needed or desired, especially basic needs.

   > **to provide = versorgen**
   >
   > We aim to **provide** the local community with more green spaces.
   >   Wir wollen die Gemeinde mit mehr Grünflächen **versorgen**.
5. To furnish (with), cause to be present.

   > **to provide with something = mit etwas ausstatten, möblieren** (*ausstatten* is also a [separable verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb))
   >
   > A carpenter **provided** our office with desks and cabinets.
   >   Ein Tischler/Schreiner **stattete** unser Büro mit Tischen und Schränken **aus**.
   >   Ein Tischler/Schreiner **möblierte** unser Büro. (If you use »möblieren«, you most often don't say with what)
6. To make possible or attainable.

   > **to provide with something = etwas geben, etwas aufzeigen** (*aufzeigen* is also a [separable verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb))
   >
   > He **provides** us with an alternative option.
   >   Er **gab** uns eine alternative Möglichkeit.
   >   Er **zeigte** uns eine alternative Möglichkeit **auf**.

Comment: +1 for "Learn: You never translate words. You always translate meanings!" That should be a banner for this site and for other languages.

Comment: Ich würde Punkt 2 noch um die Variante *Ich werde XYZ **beisteuern*** erweitern, vor allem für Situationen, in denen mehrere Leute jeweils einen Beitrag leisten (for situations where several people contribute to the result, you could use the word *beisteuern*)

Answer (score 7):

*Bereitstellen* is one of a few options in this context. If you take a look at the [Wiktionary entry to *bereitstellen*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bereitstellen), for one you'll find that it indeed means *to provide*, *to supply*, and for another you'll find a synonym that is also a quite common way of saying the same thing: *zur Verfügung stellen* (meaning, *to make available for use*).

> Ich werde die notwendigen Bücher zur Verfügung stellen.

I consider that phrase a little more common. Still, your word choice is absolutely fine.